# solution of 3rd order non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help regarding solution of this equation which has been solved in a research paper but I cant figure it out. Please help

$f^{\prime\prime\prime} + 3ff^{\prime\prime}- 3(f^{\prime})^2 - (Ha +\frac{1}{K})f^{\prime}=0$

subject to conditions $f(0)=s$, $f'(0)=1$ and $f^{\prime}(\infty)=0$.

Comment: Check out the following link to help format your question.

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I read your equation as $f''' + 3ff' - 3(f')^2 - ( H_a + \frac{1}{K})f' = 0$, and I assume $H_a$ and $K$ are constants.  Am I right?

Comment: It would help me at least to know what the solution in the paper *is*, and how it was derived.

Comment: They have not mentioned how to derive the solution just have given the solution which is $f(\eta)= s+\frac{1}{\beta}(1-e^{-{\beta\eta}})$,where 
$\beta= \frac{3s + \sqrt{9s^2 + 4(3+Ha+\frac{1}{K})}}{2}$